# Fibonacci memoization order of execution

Tags: dynamic-programming, fibonacci, memoization

The following code is fibonacci sequence using memoization. But I do not understand the order of execution in the algorithm. If we do dynamic_fib(4), it will calculate dynamic_fib(3) + dynamic_fib(2). And left side calls first, then it calculates dynamic_fib(2) + dynamic_fib(1). But while calculating dynamic_fib(3), how does the cached answer of dynamic_fib(2) propagate up to be reused when we are not saving the result to the memory address of the dictionary like &dic[n] in C.

What I think should happen is, the answer for dynamic_fib(2) is gone because it only existed in that stack. So you have to calculate dynamic_fib(2) again when calculating dynamic_fib(4)

Am I missing something?

```
def dynamic_fib(n):
    return fibonacci(n, {})

def fibonacci(n, dic):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n

    if not dic.get(n, False):
        dic[n] = fibonacci(n-1, dic) + fibonacci(n-2, dic)

    return dic[n]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `dynamic_fib` (called once) just delegates the work to `fibonacci`, where the real work is done. In `fibonacci` you have the dictionary `dic` which is used to save the values of the function once it is calculated. So, for each of the values (2-n) when you call the function `fibonacci` for the first time, it calculates the result, but it also stores it in the dictionary, so that when the next time we ask for it, we alread have it, and we don't need to travel the whole tree again. So the complexity is linear , `O(n)`.

Comment: I know that what you describe is the normal fibonacci with memoization.

Comment: However, in this case, what I am wondering is, in fibonacci(3,{}), fibonacci(2,{}) + fibonacci(1,{}) is calculated, which calls fibonacci(1,{}) + fibonacci(0,{}). So this returns 1 and save it into dic[2] = 1. However, because the dic[2] only exists in that current stack and is gone when it is propagating up, isn't dic an empty dictionary?

Comment: In C programming, this makes sense because you can pass in pointer of dictionary in the argument and we can manipulate that. But in Python, simply manipulating the argument is playing with the copy and not modifying the actual dictionary?

Comment: `dic` is passed as mutable dictionary which is like a reference to the mutable object, so at each time the dic contains the updated state. Check https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference.

Comment: @MattChoi are you convinced now?

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Do you know if Java works the same way? Passing in dictionary or list is passing mutable object like Python?

Comment: Shortly, yes. The point is that you are passing an address to where the dictionary is stored. If you just add data to it, the address is still the same, so the dictionary will get updated.